# How to remove Question and Poll actions from Feed in Salesforce Community Site

Tags: community, chatter

I have removed these Actions from Publisher Layout.
When I log in as a regular Salesforce user, I only see the Post button (which is what I want), but when I log in as a Partner Community license user, I see all 3 buttons. What could be the problem?[image]

Comment: Can you try try removing the post and poll buttons from the publisher layout under Setup-->Global action which is assigned to community profiles?

Comment: I already tried creating a different Publisher Layout and Assign it to Community User, but I still see all 3 buttons